# CouchDB reduce function with an array of values

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce

I have a map function that returns a value as an array:

```
emit(doc.created_date, { calories : doc.calories, miles : doc.miles, minutes : doc.minutes, reps : doc.reps, steps : doc.steps, water : doc.water })
```

I want to run a sum on the calories, miles, minutes and steps for all the returned values. Like

```
return {"calories":t_cal,"miles":t_mil, "minutes":t_min,"steps":t_step};
```

I have tried several of the examples the couch wiki and other sites, but i cannot figure out how to access the value array.

I get `reduce_overflow_error` when i try just summing the values or a null when running a for loop:

```
for(var i in values) { t_mil = t_mil + values[i].miles }
```

Comment: Are you wanting a sum for each of the individual fields? You probably just need to create separate indexes for each field. Yeah, it's more than 1 query, but that's probably the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 6):

I do what you are doing a lot, so it is possible.

Either your object is a *little bit* over CouchDB's limit, or there is a bug in your code.

You can set the CouchDB config, `query_server_config/reduce_limit = "false"` and see how it looks.

However, if you are only accumulating four items, I do not think it is a reduce limit issue. What always happens to me is JavaScript problems. For example, adding a number to a string produces a (longer) string. Adding more numbers makes the string longer and longer.

```
var old_value = "3" // This is a bad value, perhaps from a map function bug
var new_value = 5

new_value = new_value + old_value // I wanted 8, but I got "53"
new_value = new_value + 2012 // I wanted 2020 but I got "532012"
```

Similar problems occur for arrays and other types.

You have a good start with the `map` function emitting the same thing that `reduce` returns (an object). Perhaps you could post some code that you are using. I usually do something like this:

```
function(keys, vals, rereduce) {
  // reduce function
  var result = {'calories':0, 'miles':0, 'minutes':0, 'steps':0}

  for(var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
    result.calories += vals[i].calories || 0
    result.miles    += vals[i].miles    || 0
    result.minutes  += vals[i].minutes  || 0
    result.steps    += vals[i].steps    || 0
  }

  return result
}
```

Notice that the reduce output is exactly the same as the map output, so this code works for reducing and re-reducing.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in an elegant and fast way without JS reduce. Make your map function emit an array, like `emit(doc.created_date, [doc.calories, doc.miles, doc.minutes, doc.reps, doc.steps, doc.water])`, and then use built-in `_sum` for reduce.

Result will be an array of sums by columns. Not well known, however very useful feature of CouchDB.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I spent hours trying to figure this out.